# A countdown website pauses and resumes automatically when tab is hidden

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

So, a few days ago I created a very basic countdown website with HTML, CSS & JS. Here's the [Github repo](https://github.com/JuzerShakir/countdown) and [live here](https://juzershakir.github.io/countdown/).

Before going into the details of the issue, let me walk you through how the countdown site works. Basically, by default, the countdown is set to 5 minutes and you can start the timer by entering `s` keyword, and the timer will start. You can also set minutes manually and start the timer as described.

The countdown works perfectly fine, no issue there until the tab is hidden. I have actually performed several tests on chrome browser, both where the tab is visible on the screen and hidden.

### First test phase: (Tab: visible)

Regardless of how many minutes you set, when the tab is visible on the screen. The timer works as expected.

### Second test phase: (Tab: hidden)

I start the timer with `n` minutes and then switch to another tab. The timer works perfectly fine if the timer is set to less than ~6 minutes.
Now when the timer is set to `7` minutes or greater, then the timer automatically behind the scenes pauses itself. This will happen only if you don't visit the counter tab once you start the timer (long enough time for the browser to pause the logic).

---

### What I think of the issue

My reasoning for this issue would be that the browser automatically pauses the javascript functionality (logic) to save resources. The question is how should I overcome this?

I tried to find the answer on google, and one of them suggested is to disable `Auto Discardable` on `chrome://discards/` for the countdown tab. But this didn't work.

So, I guess the question is obvious how should I tell chrome browser to not stop the logic when the tab is no longer visible.

---

### A work-around for the issue

For time-being, I am able to use the countdown by opening it to a new window where its tab is active and have a different window for my work open which is visible to the screen. The timer works perfectly fine with no issues. So in my display (screen) I have work window active and visible and the countdown window behind it active.

### Countdown Logic

```js
function startCountdown() {
  // console.log(mins);
  // console.log(secs % 60);
  // ? when timer starts we need to show -1 min
  showMins(mins - 1);
  secs = secs - 1;
  // ? shows the seconds
  secsDisplay.textContent = secs % 60;
  // * store mins and secs to the cookie
  setCookie();
  // ? resets the timer if 0 seconds are left
  if (secs === 0) {
    clearInterval(countdown);
    timerTicking.pause();
    timesUp.play();
    resetTimer();
    // ? or min decreases by 1 if seconds is fully divisible by 60
  } else if (secs % 60 === 0) {
    mins = mins - 1;
    showMins(mins);
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue where I created a timer that users used to time their work. If the tab was not the focused tab, the timer would either stop working, or the time would be off. I believe the browser is restricting resources for hidden tabs. I ended up scrapping the timer and using a start and end time. I realize that's not exactly your issue, but hope the comment helps.

Comment: There is no solution, too many dishonest sites use various techniques (including this one) to spy and track your browsing, when it's not worse (botnet). and it saturates the internet.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I use a horse racing website, and the minutes-to-post timer regularly stops. Reloading the page corrects it. About 30 minutes ago, I added the website into Chrome's Performance Memory Saver exceptions, and it seems to have corrected it.

Comment: Can i ask how do you add the website to the Chrome's Performance Memory saver exception?

Comment: Settings/Performance/Add